# How to convert column vector into MxN matrix?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I am relatively new to C++ and kind of stuck in this problem. I have 999x1 vector of point coordinates and I want to convert it in 333x3 matrix dyanamically. Besides this, I am using different Cpp files for one project so the function which reads the points set is in different file. How to make this matrix and how should I access it in my main code? 
I tried using `vector<vector<float> > Mymatrix` thing but you need to specify the rows and column size in this kind of definition which I cannot get until I read the file. If I try to declare above Mymatrix variable in the function which is reading the pointset file, its scope gets limited and I cannot use that Mymatrix in main.cpp.
Its little bit difficult to write the code here because it has many links with other files. I hope you have got my problem! Please help me in this issue...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid "wall of text" posts

Comment: vector can grow dynamically , so why do you need to specify the rows and column size in this kind of definition ?

Answer (score 0):

vector is really just a container for array. So basically what you have is a `int A[999]` and want to convert this into `int M[333][3]`;
Considering that in memory both a 1D and a 2D array are stored in a contiguous memory region, you can achieve this in several ways:

```
 - use a pointer and two indexes i, j: the first 3 elements are your first row,
   the next 3 elements your second row and so on.

int vector<int> v;
int *p, i=0,j=0;  // i=[0..332], j=[0..2]
p=&v[0];
*(p+(i*3)+j); //this is the same as p[i][j];
```

Or declare matrix (either allocate static or dynamic memory for it) and copy all the elements int the matrix:

```
int M[333][3]; //i'll go with static allocation for this example
for(i=0;i<333;i++)
   for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      M[i][j] = v[i*3 + j];
```

choose which ever method you want - the advantage of the first one is that it does not us the extra memory.

Comment: Thanks! I later figured it out by myself.. I used exactly the same technique as your second method. Static allocation. Also I declared the function of type matrix and returned a matrix at the end to use it different file. :) 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: please upvote any helpful comments or answers you received :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your MyMatrix as a pointer and pass to your function as parameter:

```
vector<vector<float> >* Mymatrix; //Don't forget to initialize the pointer
functionThatReadsFiles(Mymatrix); //That function makes changes to Mymatrix
```

With this, any changes you make to Mymatrix inside "functionThatReadsFiles" will remain after its call. Anyway, make sure you fully understand how to operate with pointers before trying this.

As @erlc says, you can also declare your function with:

```
void functionThatReadsFiles(vector<vector<float> >& Mymatrix);
```

And call just call it normally (without pointers), and again the changes will remain into your Mymatrix.

Comment: That's just one of the multiple solutions this problem could have. Definitely the existence of another solution is not a reason for downvoting mine.

Comment: You are still using a pointer argument, why not change the parameter to a reference `void functionThatReadsFiles(vector &)`

Comment: hm sorry you're right. This is what I have for editing too quickly.